# Access Field on Lookup Relationship in trigger

Tags: trigger, soql, governorlimits

I have a `Lookup` relationship to another `custom sObject`, and I want to access: `sObject.sObject1__r.Name`

However, `sObject__r.Name` is undefined in the context of the trigger. If I attempt to run this query I quickly overflow the *SOQL Query Gov. Limit*,

Is there a way to run a single SOQL for all items in `Trigger.new` (if the trigger is called repeatedly) like one firing ***after updating a list of more than 100 items***?

Example code (hits gov. limits)

```
trigger MeetingMemberTrigger on MeetingMember__c (before insert, before update,
        after insert, after update) {

if(Trigger.isUpdate){
List<Meeting__c> meetings = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Meeting__c WHERE Id IN 
                                        (SELECT Meeting__c FROM MeetingMember__c WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new)];
for(MeetingMember__c member : Trigger.new){ 
   // do some stuff with member.Meeting__r.Name (which is undefined)
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to execute a query for all of your 'missing' related data and store the results into a map so that you can access it quickly without iterating over elements to find what you're looking for.

```
trigger MeetingMemberTrigger on MeetingMember__c (before insert, before update,
        after insert, after update) {

    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        // query for the additional data you need in the trigger
        Map<Id, MeetingMember__c> meetingMembersMap 
                    = new Map<Id, MeetingMember__c>([SELECT Id
                                                        , Meeting__r.Name 
                                                    FROM MeetingMember__c 
                                                    WHERE Id IN :Trigger.New]);

        for(MeetingMember__c triggerMember : Trigger.new){
            // retrieve the record from the map which has the related data
            MeetingMember__c queryMember = meetingMembersMap.get(triggerMember.id);

            // do stuff using queryMember.Meeting__r.Name here
            if (queryMember.Meeting__r.Name == 'something') {

                // manipulate the item in the trigger collection as necessary
                // triggerMember.SomeField__c = 'new value';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And this won't overflow the _gov. limit_ when I run `update` on a list of `MeetingMember__c` that's over 100 items?

Comment: It shouldn't; it's only executing one SOQL statement that won't return too many results.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question but I thought you were asking how to avoid re-running the query for `meeting__r.name` for every batch of 200 meetingMembers. I don't see how this solves that issue.

Comment: The original post was doing a separate query for each record in Trigger.new, and the query needed to be moved out of the loop. There will still be a query run each time this executes.

Comment: Note that this will not work on the before insert items: they don't have an id yet (id == null for items in Trigger.New).

Comment: @Legolas as written, it's all in an update context.

Comment: @MarkPond right, I saw the trigger lists 'before insert', I missed the 'if (Trigger.isUpdate)' a few lines below that, sorry!